# Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_archive_title ()

Tags: fatal-error

When I click on "Tags, Categories, Archive", this appears on page:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function the_archive_title () in
>   /home/u932610063/public_html/wp-content/themes/powen-lite/archive.php
>   on line 20

How should I fix this error?

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running?

Comment: Thanks for fast respon, 
I'm using WordPress 4.0.1 
here is my Problem ( http://grahafauzi.de/category/adventure/)

Comment: archive.php on line 20 is maybe this line:
esc_attr(the_archive_title( '<h2 class="content">', '</h2>' ));

Comment: You should really read the documentation before jumping in and using code/functions/etc

Comment: Its great... all is Done!!! thank you for this great help. Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using WordPress 4.0.1

You need to update WordPress to the latest version. [`the_archive_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_archive_title/) was added in version 4.1.

Comment: Its great... all is Done!!! thank you for this great help.
Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function intends of [the_archive_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_archive_title/)

```
get_the_archive_title()
```

`the_archive_title()` Introduced in wordpress 4.1.0 if your version less then 4.1.0 then use above one.